# Manipulate a CSV file using AWK

Tags: awk

I am new in `awk` and I was asked to format the following `csv` file (where each row stands for a day with values for each hour)

```
3244,3138,3068,3083,3231,3624,3932,4018,4095,4195,4260,4328,4400,4431,4423,4418,4377,4331,4367,4354,4220,3919,3647,3415
3280,3187,3142,3165,3353,3772,4093,4126,4151,4180,4146,4141,4111,4071,4009,3942,3902,3871,3997,4005,3838,3657,3492,3332
```

.... and so on for 5 more days, in 7 different files with the following format:

```
4    UC.DB                                  
*************************                               
*                               
***************************                         
*                                       
7 UC_SYSTEM_SCHED,2;0,2;1,2;2,2;3,2;4,2;5,2;6,2;7,2;8,2;9,2;10,2;11,2;12,2;13,2;14,2;15,2;16,2;17,2;18,2;19,2;20,2;21,2;22,2;23
1,3244,3138,3068,3083,3231,3624,3932,4018,4095,4195,4260,4328,4400,4431,4423,4418,4377,4331,4367,4354,4220,3919,3647,3415   
 0                                      
*                               
 0                                      
0
```

The purpose is to create 7 different files with this format from a `CSV` file that will have 7 different rows. As you can see, the first 7 lines will be the same for all the 7 files created (the "1," from the 8 line and 9, 10, 11, 12 lines will stay the same as well). The only difference will be the data imported for each day.

This is what I tried so far:

```
awk -F "," NR==1'{printf "4, UC.DB\n***************\n*\n***************\n*\n7,UC_SYSTEM_SCHED,2;0,2;1,2;2,2;3,2;4,2;5,2;6,2;7,2;8,2;9,2;10,2;11,2;12,2;13,2;14,2;15,2;16,2;17,2;18,2;19,2;20,2;21,2;22,2;23\n1,"}''NR==1'UC_Load_Data.csv > awk.file
```

It works just fine for the first 8 lines, but when I try to add the last 4 lines, I keep getting errors.

I know it migh not make much sense and it is confusing to understand, however, I do appreciate your time and hopefully you can help me.
Thank you..!!!

Comment: Your formatting was a mess. I tried to improve it but the output format doesn't seem fine. Please, check it because it will be helpful for all other users that wish to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong. Your:

```
awk -F "," NR==1'{printf "..."}''NR==1'UC_Load_Data.csv
```

in valid awk syntax (and assuming that trailing NR==1 is a typo) would be:

```
awk -F "," 'NR==1{printf "...\n"}' UC_Load_Data.csv
```

I THINK what you want is just something like this:

```
awk -F "," '
   BEGIN { hdr="4, UC.DB\n******"\n*\n*******\n*\n7,UC_SYSTEM_SCHED,2;0,2;...23\n" }
   { print hdr NR "," $0 > "file_" NR }
' UC_Load_Data.csv
```